# AdaBoost decision_function() outputs in binary classification with sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, adaboost

As I understand it based on some study of the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e895b42abe8d8d09105cbb82dc2cbba7/sklearn/ensemble/_weight_boosting.py#L675), I would expect, when using AdaBoost, that values obtained by calling decision_function() would be bounded between -1 and 1. This is because it's the weighed average of the probabilities. However, as you can see in the histogram below, the values seem to range from a little under -2 to a little over +2. [image: Plot of calling decision_function() on an array of 10,000 test-points.]

Why is this? Am I under some misunderstanding about how these values are calculated?

Comment: Can you provide a MRE? In particular, what's the base estimator here?